# Search the content from table in oracle

Tags: oracle, jsp, oracle11g

I need your expert suggestion, Actually I am working on a Web project (using JSP and Oracle) having multiple database tables based on categories inwhich most of columns matches in tables, Now I want to create a search functioanlity on database tables which will search only on matching columns (these column exist in all tables). To do that I was thinking to create view (union of all tables) and then perform the search on view but I think this will degrade the performation since these tables are partitioned based on state and city and having huge data.

Example :

```
Table A

Col 1
Col 2
Col 3

Table B

Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 4

Table C

Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 5
```

Just to want to perform a search on col1, Col3 and Col3 (these columns exist in all tables)

Is there any other way to create the search to optimize the performance as well..??

Please help.

Comment: The search is based on what column(s) ? Which columns are indexed in those tables ?

Comment: I just wanted to search on three above mentioned colums (col1, col2 and col3). There is no index in tables.

Comment: If you are tables are big, you need to index those columns. Try this  1)Get the explain plan for your query before creating index. 2) Create index on the Columns for those tables. 3)Do gather Stats on those tables 4) Now get the explain plan again for your query and compare it.

Comment: In the explain plan you had taken before creating index, you will see high cost and full table scans compared to the explain plan taken after creating the index. I'm posting this based on the info you gave here . There might be other things as well for the slowness. You can post the explain plan here if you can.

Comment: Thanks Balaji for explaination.. Suppose I create the index on primary key... on all the tables then what approach should I follow to search the keyword from all the tables based on above explained three columns.. Should I use view (union of all tables) or any other approach ...Please suggest.

Comment: You can use joins instead of union. But check the explain plan and decide which one is better.

Answer (score -1):

WITH table-a AS
(select col1,col3 from table1),
Table-b AS
( select col1,col3 from table1)
SELECT col1,col3
FROM table-a, table-b

Just a suggestion

Comment: but problem is there is no reference key between these tables.... all the columns are independent....